# PHP curl login with captcha failed on specific site

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to licindia with curl. But get failed the same code is working at other site.
I have used one of library for dom manipulation "simple_html_dom.php".
Website: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/
I am able to get captcha but after submitting it gives me "Error : Pl Check your Answer.."
Cookies is set properly.

```
    <?php
    require_once './simple_html_dom.php';

    $host = 'customer.onlinelic.in';

    $home_url  = 'https://' . $host . '/';
    $login_url = $home_url . 'LICEPS/Login/begin.do';

    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0';

    $headers[] = "Host: $host";
    $headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
    $headers[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    $headers[] = "Host:customer.onlinelic.in";
    $headers[] = "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5";
    $headers[] = "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


    $cookie  = 'cookie.txt';

    function getAnswer() {
        global $login_url, $headers, $cookie;

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        $html  = str_get_html($response);
        $token = $html->find('form[name="chkLoginForm"] span', 3);

        return $token;
    }

    function login() {
        global $login_url, $headers, $cookie;

        $postFiels = [
            '{actionForm.userName}' => '12349743554',
            '{actionForm.password}' => 'dfdfg56',
            '{actionForm.qreply}' => ($_POST['ans'])
        ];

        $ch       = curl_init();
        $url      = "https://customer.onlinelic.in/LICEPS/Login/secureLogin.do";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFiels));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        echo $response;
    }
    ?>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Login Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <p><?php echo getAnswer(); ?></p>
                <input type="text" name="ans" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['ans']) ? $_POST['ans'] : ''; ?>" /><br />
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                login();
            }
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

first off, there's no need to use simple_html_dom, php's built-in DOMDocument & DOMXpath is fully capable of doing this, with minimal knowledge of XPaths, i suggest you study XPaths a little (eg, `$token = $html->find('form[name="chkLoginForm"] span', 3);` probably translates to `$token=$xp->query('//form[@name="chkLoginForm"]')->item(3)->textContent;` )

second, don't do this `$headers[] = "Host: $host";`
 - curl will provide the Host header automatically. (the only instances where you'd want to provide the host header manually, as far as i can think of atm, is when you're communicating with a server that has improperly configured their DNS, a very rare event)

third, you don't actually tell curl to use your user-agent string, add that $user_agent variable to CURLOPT_USERAGENT.

fourth, you're giving the host header 2 times, that doesn't make much sense, and is probably an error (and as stated above, you should actually provide it zero times, as curl will also do it for you automatically if you don't.)

fifth, don't provide this header manually `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - curl will automatically detect when you're using this encoding type, and send the appropriate headers for you - and unlike you, curl won't make any typos in doing so. (this is also true for `multipart/form-data`-encoding btw)

with that out of the way, your real problem is that your post fields make no sense, their login request looks NOTHING like that. you try to send the username/password in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, but what they really use is `application/json` encoding. you try to send the login username in a variable called `{actionForm.userName}`, but the variable for the username is actually called `userId`. you try to send the password in a variable called `{actionForm.password}`, and you try to send it raw, but the password actually goes in a variable called `password`,  and its not sent raw, its first hashed & salted (i'm not sure what hash they use, but the candidates are `sha2-512` , `sha3-512`, and `whirlpool`, and they are using this library for the hashing: https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt ), hex encoded, and then base64-encoded after the hex encoding again. (obviously the web devs here has no idea what they're doing, as that double encoding is just a waste of cpu, ram, and bandwidth, both for their server, and for the client logging in. they could save 50% bandwidth by taking away the hex encoding), also the login form as a variable called `userRole` which seems to be hardcoded to `Customer`, and a variable called `dob` which is an ISO8601 timestamp of `the day you were born`,  as a question the login form asks you, hardcoded with the time of day being `T00:00:00`...

if your current code used to work, they must have recently redesigned their login system.

the first thing you need to do is figure out what hash they're using, and figure out where the salt is given, then re-implement that salt & hash mechanism in php,  and you must get a session cookie & salt before sending the login request, and...  send the correct variables,  with the correct encoding (aka, use json_encode()), to `https://ebiz.licindia.in/intellect-platform-services/v1.0/login/authenticate`

it won't be easy, and i can't be arsed digging further for you (unless you're willing to pay for it)